# How to make a struct that uses Callable (callAsFunction()) works with protocol?

Tags: swift, function, functional-programming, callable

I'm trying to make the `callAsFunction()` works when working directly with `protocol` or `dependency injection`, but it seems like the `protocol instance` is not aware of the `Callable` feature. I tried adding the `func callAsFunction()` within the `protocol decorating`, but it did not work too. As you can see the sample code below, when creating an instance with the concrete struct, I'm able to work with the `callAsFunction()`, but not with the protocol instance.

```
protocol Decorating {
  //to implement
}

struct Decorate: Decorating {
 func callAsFunction() {
    print("Decorated!")
 }
}

let decorate: Decorate = Decorate()
decorate() //worked

let decorate2: Decorating = Decorate()
decorate2() //failed
```

Comment: How about adding `func callAsFunction()` to the protocol?

Comment: @Sweeper yes I did that as above, but it did not work.

Comment: works for me. What system are you using?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Xcode 14.1, macOS 13, CommandLineTool App with Swift 5.7

Comment: tested on macOS 13.2 only app, and separately on ios 16 and macCatalyst, all seems to work for me, using Xcode 14.2. Have not tested with a CommandLineTool App  yet.

Comment: work also for me with a CommandLineTool App. Using `protocol Decorating {
    func callAsFunction()
}`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine @Sweeper I have reimplemented the code with your suggestions and restarted my Xcode. Now, it worked. The problem was Xcode auto-completion was not aware of the `Callable`, plus the compiler did not recognize the feature for some reasons, but adding the func into protocol again + restarting the IDE worked.

Comment: a good start to the new year then.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your protocol:

```
protocol Decorating {

}

extension Decorating {
    func callAsFunction() -> {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
protocol Decorating {
    var foo: Foo
}

extension Decorating {
    func callAsFunction() -> {
        foo.foo()
    }
}

let decorate: Decorating = Decorate()
decorate()
```